# Reformat Markdown files to a specific code style

Tags: shell, markdown, github-flavored-markdown, reformatting

I'm working on a book which had a couple of people writing and editing the text. Everything is Markdown. Unfortunately, there is a mix of different styles and lines widths. Technically this isn't a problem but it's not nice in terms of aesthetics.

What is the best way to reformat those files in e.g. GitHub markdown style? Is there a shell script for this job?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might want to look at [Pandoc](http://pandoc.org); it understands several flavors of Markdown.

```
pandoc -f markdown -t gfm foobar.md
```

Having written a markup converter years ago in Perl, I would not want to approach such a task without a decent lexical analyzer, which is a bit beyond shell scripting.

Comment: it removed the metadata from my files, as well as messed up my chapter list, but it's good at formatting lines at 80 characters

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a tool called [tidy-markdown](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tidy-markdown) that will reformat any Markdown (including GFM) according to [this styleguide](https://github.com/slang800/markdown-styleguide).

```
$ tidy-markdown < ./ugly-markdown.md > ./clean-markdown.md
```

It handles conversion of inline HTML to Markdown, normalization of syntactic elements like code blocks (converting them to fenced), lists, block-quotes, front-matter, headers, and will even attempt to standardize code-block language identifiers.